# ffmpeg and mapping against 2 target audio tracks!

Tags: ffmpeg

Im trying to mux and encode a TS file with 2 audio tracks from a mov file.

```
ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -i test.mov -map 0:1 -map 0:2
-acodec:0 aac -ab 160k  -acodec:1 eac3 -ac 6 -ar 48000 -ab 640k -dialnorm -24 -dsur_mode 0 -original 1 -dmix_mode 2 -channel_layout 63   -y test.ts
```

Im ending up with 2 audiotracks, both EAC3..

Source output:

```
ffprobe version N-94156-g93a73df54d Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190621
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 30.100 / 56. 30.100
  libavcodec     58. 53.101 / 58. 53.101
  libavformat    58. 28.101 / 58. 28.101
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 56.100 /  7. 56.100
  libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
[h264 @ 000001c37707e640] Reinit context to 1920x1088, pix_fmt: yuv420p10le
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 's:\test.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt
    encoder         : Lavf58.21.100
  Duration: 00:02:28.61, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 61419 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(nor): Video: h264 (High 10), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p10le(left), 1920x1080 (1920x1088) [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 52197 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Lavc58.36.100 libx264
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit), 2304 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 5.1, s32 (24 bit), 6912 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 3
```

Anyone know whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use

`ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -i test.mov -map 0:1 -map 0:2
-codec:a:0 aac -b:a:0 160k  -codec:a:1 eac3 -ac:a:1 6 -ar:a:1 48000 -b:a:1 640k -dialnorm -24 -dsur_mode 0 -original 1 -dmix_mode 2 -channel_layout 63 -y test.ts`

`acodec` is an alias for `codec:a` and it does not accept stream specifiers. Same goes for other codec-related options like bitrate.

Comment: Seems that ure answer partly helped the situation, as now both AAC and eAC3 are present in the mux.. But the AAC track is 5.1, but the source track is stereo. The eAC3 track is 5.1 as the source..

Comment: It's the channel_layout. That will force all output tracks to that layout. Remove it.

Comment: That did the trick.. I got a rogue mpeg2 video track in addition.. but i muxed it out! Thx!